# React/Javascript manipulate AWS listUser array into flattened array

Tags: javascript, reactjs, arrays, amazon-web-services, amazon-cognito

I am using the AWS Cognito listUsers API to get a list of all my users from my Cognito pool. I have successfully managed to return the array of users but I'm now stuck on how to transform that array into a flattened array. Here is an example of the data I receive from the AWS listUsers API:

```
    [
        {
            Username: "xx001",
            Attributes: [
                {
                    Name: "given_name",
                    Value: "Jeff"
                },
                {
                    Name: "family_name",
                    Value: "Smith"
                },
                {
                    Name: "email",
                    Value: "jeff.smith@email.com"
                }
            ],
            UserStatus: "Confirmed",
        },
        {
            Username: "yy002",
            Attributes: [
                {
                    Name: "given_name",
                    Value: "Steve"
                },
                {
                    Name: "family_name",
                    Value: "Jones"
                },
                {
                    Name: "email",
                    Value: "steve.jones@email.com"
                }
            ],
            UserStatus: "Confirmed",
        }
    ]
```

I would like to transform the above array into the following structure:

```
[
    {
        Username: "xx001",
        given_name: "Jeff",
        family_name: "Smith",
        email: "jeff.smith@email.com",
        UserStatus: "Confirmed"
    },
    {
        Username: "yy002",
        given_name: "Steve",
        family_name: "Jones",
        email: "steve.jones@email.com"
        UserStatus: "Confirmed"
    }
]
```

If anyone could point me in the right direction it would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: you can use map to transform the array

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can use `map` to transform the array

```js
const users = [        {            Username: "xx001",            Attributes: [                {                    Name: "given_name",                    Value: "Jeff"                },                {                    Name: "family_name",                    Value: "Smith"                },                {                    Name: "email",                    Value: "jeff.smith@email.com"                }            ],            UserStatus: "Confirmed",        },        {            Username: "yy002",            Attributes: [                {                    Name: "given_name",                    Value: "Steve"                },                {                    Name: "family_name",                    Value: "Jones"                },                {                    Name: "email",                    Value: "steve.jones@email.com"                }            ],            UserStatus: "Confirmed",        }    ]
    
const res = users.map(({Attributes,...rest}) => {
  const attrObj = Attributes.reduce((acc,{Name,Value}) => ({...acc, [Name]:Value}),{})
  return {...rest,...attrObj }
 })
 
console.log(res)
```

if the attributes are fixed and not dynamic you don't even have to use `reduce` and spread. Therefore this will be faster than the first.

```js
const users = [        {            Username: "xx001",            Attributes: [                {                    Name: "given_name",                    Value: "Jeff"                },                {                    Name: "family_name",                    Value: "Smith"                },                {                    Name: "email",                    Value: "jeff.smith@email.com"                }            ],            UserStatus: "Confirmed",        },        {            Username: "yy002",            Attributes: [                {                    Name: "given_name",                    Value: "Steve"                },                {                    Name: "family_name",                    Value: "Jones"                },                {                    Name: "email",                    Value: "steve.jones@email.com"                }            ],            UserStatus: "Confirmed",        }    ]
    
const res = users.map(({Attributes,Username,UserStatus}) => {  
  return {Username,UserStatus, [Attributes[0]["Name"]]:Attributes[0]["Value"],[Attributes[1]["Name"]]:Attributes[1]["Value"],[Attributes[2]["Name"]]:Attributes[2]["Value"]}
 })
 
console.log(res)
```